# Why is there still nondeterminism in my automaton?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

I've been solving some exercises recently and it appears my answer was wrong for this particular example. The task is to convert this NFA into a DFA:

[image]

My attempt is this:

[image]

Now the tool I'm using (Exorciser) says that there is still nondeterminism in the automaton (even though it's equivalent to the original).

I don't see it; where is the mistake?

Comment: The non-determinism comes from the state {q0, q2} because on input b, there are two transitions i.e. the self loop on {q0, q2} itself and second the transition to state q2. So when the NFA reaches the state {q0, q2} - it has two options of taking a transition and has to <b>non-deterministically</b> decide on which state to take a transition.

Comment: Similarly, you can figure out where else your mistake was by following this concept, I recommend following a Powerset Construction algorithm by which mistakes are minimal.

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/). If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there. (Also, much relevant information is solely avaible in the picture, i.e. what the issue is.)

Comment: I edited your question into shape; this is the minimal effort we usually expect *you* to expend.

Comment: As for your question: there are several algorithms for this kind of conversion. Which did you employ? Check your steps -- you made a mistake somewhere. Finding the non-determinism is easy: just look for a node with two outgoing edges that share a label. So I'm not quite sure what kind of answer you are expecting here.

Answer (score 3):

The non-determinism comes from the state `{q0, q2}` because on input `b`, there are two transitions i.e. the self loop on `{q0, q2}` itself and second the transition to state `q2`. So when the NFA reaches the state `{q0, q2}` - it has two options of taking a transition and has to **non-deterministically** decide which state to take a transition to.

Following this mini-method I told above, you can figure out where you are wrong.

However, for conversion of NFA's to DFA's, I recommend following a Powerset Construction algorithm by which mistakes are minimal.